# Light coming out of nowhere

Tags: light

Hey so basically the problem is that i have a scene with a campfire and a panda, and there is a light coming from the bewlow the panda and i dont know whats causing it, i dont have any source of light other than the campfire. Any ideas to solvate the problem?

[image: Text]

Comment: have you used an Emission shader for your panda? Check its material in the Shader Editor...

Comment: the panda has 3 materials, 2 of which only has a diffuse bsdf node and output, and the other its the fur material with an image with color space in sRGB

Comment: maybe share your file so we can check: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: heres the link to the scene! [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3eWB2D0r" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3eWB2D0r/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've directly plugged the *Image Texture* into the *Output*, in that case it acts like an *Emission* shader, what you need to do is plug a *Diffuse* shader between the *Image Texture* and the *Output*:

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you! i guess thats a rookie mistake haha, thank you for helping me man, greetings from Argentina